# Misclassifying ONLY on one label in a multiclass NLP task

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, xgboost, text-classification, multiclass-classification

Working on a NLP classification task in R. Best results so far is XGBoost. Currently working on feature engineering on training set (n = 439) with some generic features and custom binary features.

```
── Recipe ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

── Inputs 
Number of variables by role
outcome:    1
predictor: 10

── Operations 
• Tokenization for: V1
• Stop word removal for: V1
• Text filtering for: V1
• Term frequency-inverse document frequency with: V1
• Zero variance filter on: all_predictors()
• Centering and scaling for: all_predictors()
• Linear combination filter on: all_numeric()
```

Having issues with one label `age` with false negative prediction on another label `gender` . On the confusion matrix scores for `age` is obviously `0` and `gender` is `0.3` when misclassifying true `age` label instances. Of note, the classification may vary as both train and test sets are split on the fly, rather residing on once-off generated files on a drive, and because of the small samples I am able to split the data as part of the downstream task. The training data is fairly balance but samples are small! but I don't think that is the problem.

Tried the following:

- optimising the model parameters
- removing special characters including periods and commas
- doing some feature extraction (extracting word relevant to label)
- doing some feature selection by removing any correlated features to 'age'

But, still consistently misclassifying on that one label!! Haven't yet test it against the test set, as I want to avoid overfitting the model, but a little counterintuitive already as I was the annotator of the full set a fair while back.

Could this be an issue with the data (ie, lack of instances for age)? Or is it something else?